# I want my iphone to change color when I shake it. How do I implement this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want my iPhone to change color when I shake it. There are plenty of applications that do this, and I want my iPhone to do the same. Could anybody send me a link helping me on the topic?

Comment: First you need to invent some colour changing material to coat your iPhone with. Once you've done that you'll be rich. Also, go and accept some answers to your previous questions.

Comment: Babies seem to change colour when you shake them, that might be worth a bit of study.

Comment: I tried covering my iPhone with chameleon skin. Now I can't find it.

Comment: @Dave: I don't think that you are allowed to wrap an iPhone in baby skin.

Comment: @MikeJ-UK: Thats why they invented Find My iPhone.

Comment: Humph! No good me putting that as an answer, then.

Comment: @middaparka: I know, I reminded him and he still hasn't accepted my 5-point answer to his previous question. Shame, really.

Comment: If you find a solution, could you send me a link too? Been waiting for a white iPhone for ages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking to do is respond to a UIEvent specifically the UIEventSubtypeMotionShake.  Read the article on the UIEvent.  Event control is at the core of Iphone dev.  Read strait through take notes and have fun.